# User login events lags time issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I'm facing some issues with User login events lags time. I read article about it and Google claim it take up to few hours:

https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7061566?hl=en

I tested it in on my lab and it's true - user login events shows after 1,5-4h! It is ridiculous. How can build some security monitoring for users based on that? If someone will compromise some user account I cannot react properlly. I created ticket to Google but all I got is: as documentation said - this is as expected.

I'm wondering how you guys build your own monitoring for user login activity? Is there any way to speed this logs up? Maybe you can recommend me some services/tools/3rd parties solutions or Google architecture design that might help me?

Many thanks!